# C fprintf program outputing -1.#J instead of real numbers

Tags: c

Statement in program:

```
fprintf(OutBasalArea,"\t %12.2lf",SpecBasalArea[ks]);
```

Getting -1.#J
Why and what change do I need to make to program statement?

Comment: What type is `SpecBasalArea`?

Answer (score 2):

This happens because your number is -infinite.

Try to print the numbers without the length specifier 12.2 (use just %lf ). In this case, the output will be:
-1.#INF00 (or something like that).